# DB Deployment using DBDeloy

Tags: web-applications

There isn't much documentation on the website http://dbdeploy.com/ regarding using the exe version of dbdeploy (.NET version).  Trying to use it without parameters give me the message:

usage: dbdeploy propertyfilename

Anyone know what the expected format of the propertyfile is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DBDeploy:

If you downloaded the [zip file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdeploy-net/files/dbdeploy-net/1.0/dbdeploy.net.zip/download) there is an example in the example folder.

If you're doing .NET development and have a copy of Visual Studio, there is a vsdbcmd.exe that will let you do a command line database deployment.

Comment: Saw the examples, but given they had a exe file I was trying to use that rather than through a separate nant script.